# C# TaskScheduler Несоответствие версии схемы

Tags: c#, windows, .net-6, планировщик-задач

Я использую [TaskScheduler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskScheduler/2.10.1) для создания задачи в Планировщике заданий Windows, которая запускает приложение с правами Администратора и с указанными аргументами в заданное время:

```
using (var taskService = new TaskService()) {
    TaskDefinition definition = taskService.NewTask();
    definition.Principal.RunLevel = TaskRunLevel.Highest;
    definition.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Description";
    definition.Triggers.Add(new EventTrigger() { StartBoundary = taskActivationTime });
    definition.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(appPath, startupArgs, null));
    taskService.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("ExampleTask", definition);
}
```

В результате выполнения от имени Администратора возникает следующее исключение: `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: '(12,8):Subscription:'`

Я попробовал сохранить определение в формате XML (`definition.XmlText`) и импортировать задачу напрямую через Планировщик заданий - отображается сообщение об ошибке: "Неверный формат задачи". Версия схемы, используемой в моём Планировщике заданий - 1.6, версия схемы, используемой TaskScheduler - 1.2. Если убрать строчку с добавлением триггера, то добавление происходит успешно. Как можно исправить?

Версия ОС: Windows 10 21H2

Comment: Версия дотнета какая? А вообще такие вопросы лучше разработчику NuGet пакета задавать. Ну либо поищите другой NuGet пакет.

Comment: Версия .NET 6.0

Comment: Я заменил `EventTrigger` на `TimeTrigger` и это сработало. Посмотрел XML схему задачи с таким триггером в Планировщике и обратил внимание, что в моей схеме используется `EventTrigger`, а в схеме добавленной задачи тег `TimeTrigger`.

Comment: То есть версия схемы была ни при чём.